# Menu active sheet SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to create a menu in SwiftUI with the possibility of showing sheets, but when I try to display the menu the sheets doesn't display.
Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
    case first, second
    
    var id: Int {
        hashValue
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    @State private var showingConfirmation = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Menu("Actions") {
            
            VStack {
                Button {
                    activeSheet = .first
                } label: {
                    Text("Activate first sheet")
                }
                
                Button {
                    activeSheet = .second
                } label: {
                    Text("Activate second sheet")
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
                switch item {
                case .first:
                    FirstView()
                case .second:
                    SecondView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The actual result is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne4nh.png)
But without any possibility of access to the sheet pages I created.
Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `.sheet` to outside the `Menu`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    @State private var showingConfirmation = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Menu("Actions") {
            
            VStack {
                Button {
                    activeSheet = .first
                } label: {
                    Text("Activate first sheet")
                }
                
                Button {
                    activeSheet = .second
                } label: {
                    Text("Activate second sheet")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
            switch item {
            case .first:
                FirstView()
            case .second:
                SecondView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```